# Remapping Keyboard Volume Controls

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, volume-control

I want to use this keyboard with Ubuntu (12.04):

[http://www.amazon.com/Filco-Majestouch-2-Tenkeyless-FKBN87ML-EFB2/dp/B0050ODQEI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0050ODQEI)

It has no media keys.

What I'm wondering is, will I be able to remap the 'Print Screen', 'Scroll Lock' and 'Pause Break' keys to the volume controls ('Mute', 'Down', 'Up'), without activating their original functions, or anything else (i.e. Screenshot, etc)?

Or, do you have a better solution for what keys I can remap the volume controls to?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a basic PC keyboard, a Logitech K120, and it also does not have media buttons.

I have tried setting the Print Screen, Scroll Lock, and Pause/break keys to Mute, Volume down, and Volume up; in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

They all were recognized and added to the configuration, but the Scroll Lock key for the Volume Down did not work. Print Screen and Pause/Break for Mute and Volume Up worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up getting the keyboard, and I have the exact same thing; Scroll Lock does not work. So I ended up mapping Print Screen to Volume Down, and Pause Break to Volume Up, and just did without Mute. I'm not sure why Scroll Lock doesn't work. I wish it did. Anyway, I really like the keyboard, and everything else on it works great. Thanks again!